# "si vous auriez" avec "si" non conditionnel

Tags: grammaire, subordonnées, conditionnel, interrogative

Bien que le *si* marquant une condition ne puisse pas être suivi du conditionnel, je me demande si cette règle s'applique également avec un *si* ne marquant pas une condition.

Exemples :

> Je voulais savoir **si tu aurais** le temps de venir m'aider.
>
> Je me demandais **si vous auriez** besoin de mes services.

Je ne ressent pas le *si* comme l'expression d'une condition mais comme une forme d'interrogation... mais peut-être que je fais l'erreur (et que je la vois faire) depuis longtemps. Bien que peu élégantes, ces formulations sont-elles correctes ?

Answer (score 5):

En fait, dans la construction indiquée, le conditionnel présent est utilisé pour exprimer un futur dans le passé. C'est lié à la concordance des temps et non à l'expression d'une hypothèse, même si l'interprétation peut varier:

> je me demande si tu auras le temps...
>
> je me demandais si tu aurais le temps...

Comment: Du conditionnel pour exprimer un futur dans le passe ? Normalement, c'est le role du futur anterieur, pas du conditionnel passe.

Comment: le futur antérieur est le passé du futur (Le film sera terminé lorsque je rentrerai), pas le futur du passé.

Comment: Effectivement. Je reste circonspect, je dois avouer ;)

Comment: j'ai un peu nuancé ma réponse car il est vrai que plusieurs interprétations sont possibles.

Comment: cela n'offre-t-il pas une similitude avec le discours indirect ? Correspondant à « Je me demande : auras-tu le temps de […] »

Comment: Exactement. Je me demandais : "Auras-tu le temps de ...?" devient 'Je me demandais si tu aurais le temps de ...?'. Idem avec 'je disais: "Tu auras le temps de ...?" qui devient 'Je disais que tu aurais le temps de...'

Comment: Merci, aurais-tu des sources ?